is it possible to write custom terraform functions?
Is it possible to write custom terraform functions?
If yes, how to write them?
Tryied this tutorial but is there no mention of custom terraform functions.

In what Language?

python, for example

The Terraform language does not support user-defined functions

Yes you can develop custom Terraform functions, but it requires a recent version of the Terraform Plugin SDK (if the functions are developed in Go), and Terraform version >= 1.8. If you want to develop the functions in a language other than Go, then you would need to reproduce plugin SDK functionality (which would be onerous). The documentation contains more details.
If you want to develop the functions in a language other than Go, and are content with the functionality being very similar, but not literally a custom function, then you would want the external data source. You can provide JSON format inputs to and return JSON format outputs from an arbitrary executable in a given language.
